# In Terraform is it possible to have a local in a variable?

Tags: variables, terraform, local-variables

```
locals {
  pet_name = dog
}
```

```
variable "colors" {
  default = "${local.pet_name}"
```

I'm currently getting a "Variables may not be used here" error message.

Comment: Default values of type String in variable declarations must be literal.

Answer (score 0):

A default value for an input variable must be a literal value, since it's part of the documentation of the module's API and so is written to be understandable by the user of the module without them needing to look at the rest of the module's source code.

If you want to handle the variable being unset in a more dynamic way, the best approach is to set the default to just `null` and then handle that case inside the implementation of your module.

For example:

```
variable "example_thing" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

locals {
  default_example_thing = "dog"
  actual_example_thing  = coalesce(var.example_thing, local.default_example_thing)
}
```

You can then use `local.actual_example_thing` instead of `var.example_thing` elsewhere in your module to get the final result with the default having been applied. In this case this approach adds nothing because `"dog"` would've been a fine value to assign to `default` in the variable declaration, but I assume that in practice you intend to use a dynamic value such as a `data` block result to populate the default. If that's true then you may also want to add a conditional `count` to the `data` block to avoid fetching the default value whenever `var.example_thing != null`.

This approach does mean that the user of your module won't be able to see just from the `variable` block what happens when the variable set, so I would recommend also adding a `description` argument which summarizes the behavior in natural language, as a substitute for the explicit default value.